# How to clear a navigation graph from backstack in nested navigation in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, jetpack

I have made a nested navigation using bottom navigation graph and other graphs i want the backstack to be cleared till the last graph?
i have my navigation as below

```
@Composable
fun HomeNavGraph(navcontroller:NavHostController){
    val viewmodel:MainCategoryViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            NavHost(navController = navcontroller, startDestination = "Home_Screen" ){
        composable("Home_Screen"){
            HomeScreen(navcontroller,viewmodel)
        }
        composable("Search_Screen"){
            SearchScreen()
        }
        composable("Shopping_Cart_Screen"){
            ShoppingCartScreen(navcontroller,viewmodel)
        }

        composable("Profile_Screen"){
            ProfileScreen()
        }
        composable("Product_Navigation_Graph"){
                    ProductNavigationGraph( mainCategoryViewModel = viewmodel )

        }
        composable("Checkout_Navigation_Graph"){
            CheckoutNavigationGraph( )
        }


    }
}

@Composable
fun CheckoutNavigationGraph(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "Address_Details_Screen" ){

        composable("Address_Details_Screen"){
                AddressDetailsScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable("Add_New_Address_Screen"){
        AddNewAddressScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable("Payment_Screen"){
        PaymentScreen(navController)
        }
        composable("Billing_Screen"){
            var address= navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<Address>("address")


            BillingScreen(navController,address)
        }
    }
}
```

I am first going to checkout navigation from homenavgraph and in payment screen i want the all back stack to be cleared and reach at the last screen from which i entered in checkout navigation (for eg. Shopping_Cart_Screen)

I tried ->

```
navController.navigate("Shopping_Cart_Screen"){
                        popUpTo("Shopping_Cart_Screen"){
                            inclusive = false
                        }
                    }
```

This shows error that destination is not found
and

```
navController.popBackStack(
                        "Shopping_Cart_Screen",inclusive = false
                    )
```

this shows ->  Ignoring popBackStack to route Shopping_Cart_Screen as it was not found on the current back stack

Comment: Which NavController are you calling those methods on? The outer one and the inner one are completely independent from one another with how you have it set up so calling something on the inner one with destinations from the outer one is never going to work (which is why using multiple NavControllers is not a recommended pattern at all).

Comment: @ianhanniballake i am calling on the inner one first i am navigating from homenavgraph to checkoutnavigation and in checkout navigation i want to clear the backstack till the last screen from which i entered the checkout navigation (for eg - cart_screen -> address_screen -> billing_screen now in billing screen i want to go to cart screen clearing address_screen and billing screen from the backstack entry

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am using the bottom navigation bar in homenavgraph so which other types of making nested navigation help me to achieve the same functionality?